# Token Authentication and logout functionality

Tags: rest, authentication, token

In a very basic Token authentication the login process in nothing but providing the credentials and obtain the token. With RESTful API, the token is included in the header for any API calls to imply that the user is logged in.

My question is, what would the logout procedure look like?

- Deleting the token at server-side? What if the user is going to logout from web but wanna stay logged-in in mobile app?
- Deleting the token from client side? Should the server not enforcing that?
- How should the server go about invalidating a token?

How are logout mechanism implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the logout action simply invalidate the token on the server side (delete it in your database, set a flag expired to false, ...). If you want to support several kinds of REST clients, you should be able to specify for which device you want to obtain a security token. In this case, you will be able to invalidate them separately.

To provide the device kind, you can levevage the header `user-agent` or provide your own header.

Perhaps this link could help you in the design of your token management: http://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.

You talked about a Web mode. For this use case (which is a bit particular since the browser holds the token for you implicitely), I suppose that you leverage cookies. So yes, for such particular use case, the corresponding cookie must also be invalidated.

Hope it helps.
Thierry